# Scala: Use implicits in companion object

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, implicit-conversion, implicit, companion-object

I am creating companion object in scala and trying to use `object` implictis functions in `class` without import. But whenever, trying to compile the code I am getting an **error**: `type mismatch;` seems it is not able to import implictis automatically. Following is my code:

```
object ImplicitTest5 {
    implicit def dollarToRupa(dollar: Dollar): Rupa = { 
        println("calling .... dollarToEuro") 
        Rupa(dollar.value)
    } 

    implicit def dollarToEuro(dollar: Dollar): Euro = { 
        println("calling .... dollarToEuro") 
        Euro(dollar.value)
    } 
}

case class Dollar(value: Double)

case class Euro(value: Double)

case class Rupa(value: Double)

class ImplicitTest5 { 

    private val value = "String"

    def conversion = {
        val euro: Euro  = Dollar(3.1)
        println(s" ----- $euro")
    }
}
```

When i am using `import ImplicitTest5._` in my class, it will compile and run fine. According to [Programming in Scala, Page: 478](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0981531687) it will be working fine, and there is no need to define import.

> In this case, the conversion **dollarToEuro** is said to be associated to
>   the type Dollar. The compiler will find such an associated conversion
>   every time it needs to convert from an instance of type Dollar.
>   There’s no need to import the conversion separately into your program.

Something is going wrong with my sample or my understandings are misleading ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Something is going wrong with my sample or my understandings are
>   misleading

The conversion to `Dollar` will be associated with it if you define it inside `Dollar`s companion object. Currently, all your implicits are defined on `ImplicitTest5`, which isn't where the compiler looks for implicits in regards to the `Dollar` class. This forces you to explictly import the object containing those implicits. Instead, do:

```
case class Dollar(value: Double)
object Dollar {
  implicit def dollarToEuro(dollar: Dollar): Euro = {
    println("calling .... dollarToEuro")
    Euro(dollar.value)
  }
}
```

For more, see ["Where does Scala look for implicits"](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html)

Comment: Hey @Yuval, if we look in book, The Dollar is not our `case class`, It is simple class.

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara It doesn't matter, be it a `case class` or a `class`, it will see if it has a companion object defined, and if it does, look for the implicit there. It won't look inside `ImplicitTest5` for an implicit defined on `Dollar`.

Comment: Hey @Yuval i get your point, my understandings are misleading. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

By default scala compiler will look into the companion object of source and target objects. So if for example you are converting from Dollor to Euro, the implicit method can be in Dollor or Euro companion object. The compiler will pick it automatically. Otherwise you have to bring it explicitly in the scope.